# Find number of node which contain a specific word

Tags: xml, flash

Here is a common xml structure and I need length of nodes which is contain word 'yes'.
eg. here we see the node which is contain 'yes' is 2.

How to find these length?

```
<floor1>
    <block>no</block>
    <block>no</block>   
    <block>yes</block>  
    <block>no</block>   
    <block>no</block>   
    <block>yes</block>          
</floor1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [XPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) in Java 7:

```
InputSource source = new InputSource("count.xml");
Number count = (Number) XPathFactory.newInstance()
    .newXPath()
    .evaluate("count(//block[text()='yes'])", source, XPathConstants.NUMBER);
```